# Can I take all 3 tablets of Magnesium at one time or should I take 1 tablet after each meal

Tags: supplements, vitamins

I cannot take Calcium as it forms Kidney Stones, I have been told by my doctor that I have early signs of Osteoporosis.   I was told that I could take Magnesium, the bottle states 3 tablets a day with meals.  Can I take all 3 after Dinner or should I spread them out over the day?

Comment: Off topic per new [FAQ]

Comment: This is now deemed as off-topic per the [FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) and will be closed. Only nutrition questions related to exercise are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been told by your doctor that you have early signs of osteoporosis you should discuss with your doctor exactly what and how you should take your supplements.

Here is a [site about osteoporosis](http://www.nof.org/newlydiagnosed) that will give you more information so that you can be informed when you talk to your doctor.  The site mentions [food sources of calcium](http://www.nof.org/aboutosteoporosis/prevention/calcium) and discusses [vitamin D](http://www.nof.org/aboutosteoporosis/prevention/vitamind) but does not mention magnesium other than to say:

> Minerals such as magnesium, phosphorus and vitamin K are also important for bone health, but are usually obtained by eating a well-balanced diet. Most experts recommend that people take multivitamins or supplements only when they are not able to get enough nutrients from foods.

You will also want to ask your doctor or healthcare provider about [types of exercises](http://www.nof.org/aboutosteoporosis/prevention/exercise) that are appropriate for you at your stage of osteoporosis.

Answer (score 0):

You should spread them out over the whole day. Too much magnesium at one time may result in diarrhea, and if you distribute it over the day your body will take up more of it.

Keep in mind though that magnesium comes in many different forms, and there are differences between those forms. Generally the organic compounds, such as magnesium citrate, are much more effective than the inorganic forms, such as magnesium oxide. The magnesium you can buy at the supermarket is often in oxide form, and won't help you much. If nothing is specified on the package, it's probably oxide.

One of the newer forms of magnesium is the time-released form, such as the one offered by Jigsaw Health. The advantage to this is that your body will take up a much greater share of it, and you have a lesser risk of diarrhea. It's also more expensive though.

As a final remark, I recommend having your magnesium levels tested, both serum levels and RBC levels, to check what your magnesium status is. If there is zero evidence of deficiency, it's quite pointless to take magnesium supplements in the first place.